# Почему у псевдомассива NodeList есть метод Array.prototype.forEach?

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

`document.body.childNodes` - это объект, который наследует все свои свойства от `Object.prototype`. Одновременно он не является массивом, поскольку

`Array.isArray(document.body.childNodes) = false`.

Но тогда каким образом он наследует свойство `Array.prototype.forEach`?

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(document.body.childNodes)); // childNodes - не массив
console.log(typeof document.body.childNodes); 
console.log(document.body.childNodes.hasOwnProperty("forEach")); // в самом childNodes forEach метода нет
console.log("forEach" in document.body.childNodes); // но у него есть метод массива Array.prototype.forEach



document.body.childNodes.forEach(function(){
  console.log("go forEach")
}) // тем не менее forEach работает
```

Comment: Где-то читал, что `forEach` был специально добавлен не так давно. И поддерживается не всеми браузерами

Comment: Может `childNodes` экземпляр класса `NodeList`?

Comment: `.childNodes` - это метод который есть у каждого Node. Метод `Node.childNodes` возвращает коллекцию `NodeList`, которая не является массивом, а является объектом.
  Цепочка прототипов `NodeList` выглядит следующим образом: 
`myNodeList --> NodeList.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null`. В объекте `NodeList.prototype` есть только один метод : `item`. 
 
 Источник знаний: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Comment: откуда предположение. что это _метод массива_, а не просто метод?

Comment: Действительно, пользуясь дебагером можно определить, что наш `NodeList` ссылается на `NodeList.prototype`, в котором определён свой `forEach()`.

Comment: @ВладЖадченко, в IE этого метода не будет в прототипе